# react-native-azure-ad not launching with latest update of Expo app

Tags: react-native, expo

[image: Getting this error with the latest Expo App update]

To fix it, I also update iphone to the latest version.
Is it an issue with react-native-azure-ad OR expo ?

Getting below error: 
[image: THis error appears in Expo client]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get this error:

> `ScrollView` has no propType for native prop `RCTScrollView.onScrollAnimationEnd` of native type `BOOL`
>
> If you haven't changed this prop yourself this usually means that your versions of the native code and JavaScript code are out of sync. Updating both should make this error go away.

It's very likely that your device is trying to run JS code that doesn't correspond to the native code on your device. The first thing to do is look at your Expo SDK version. In app.json, you should see a field called "sdkVersion" -- for example, it might be "21.0.0" -- which tells the Expo client which version of the native code to run.

#### Using the correct version of React Native

We highly recommend that you use a release of React Native that has been tested to work with Expo. In the case of SDK 21, you'd put this in your package.json's "dependencies" section:

```
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-21.0.2.tar.gz",
```

**The above snippet works only for Expo SDK 21! If you are using a different SDK version, you must use a different version of React Native!**

#### Clearing your caches

We also want to ensure that your device doesn't try to run a stale copy of your code. There are several caches with Expo and React Native, so let's clear them just to be safe:

- Stop the React Native packager. Close exp or XDE.
- Force quit the Expo client on your device
- Clear the Watchman cache (if you are using Watchman): `watchman watch-del-all`
- Clear the Metro bundler cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*`
- Make sure your npm dependencies are rebuilt and installed correctly: `yarn --force`
- Start up exp (`exp start --clear` to make sure we clear the Metro bundler cache for good) or XDE
- Open your project on your device in the Expo client

Comment: The solution didnt solve the problem. I have also updated the output from Expo client. Hope it rings a bell.

Comment: I commented the code that checks the prop types and that unblocked me